# Find ALL cocoa classes that are singleton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

There are several system classes in Cocoa that are singletons, such as UIApplication, NSNotificationCenter. Now, I want to find all classes that are singleton, any suggestion that how could I quickly find them all?

I'm working on a huge codebase, and I need to separate the system singleton object from the customized singleton.

Comment: In Xcode you can press command-shift-O (the letter "oh", not the number zero) and search for "shared" and you'll see a fairly promising start. You might also search for "default" and "main", too, to find other singleton-like objects. But perhaps you can elaborate what precisely you mean by "I need to separate the system singleton object from the customized singleton". What is "the system singleton" and what is this "customized singleton"? Please just edit/clarify you question, rather than posting comments down below. I'm trying to understand what problem you're trying to solve...

Comment: You can also use the "symbol navigator" by pressing command-2, and again search for "default". You'll want to unselect the "show only project-defined symbols" option next to the search box. You can then quickly fly through, focusing on those `class` properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objective-C runtime hackery! Fun!

Now, before I continue, I will present the disclaimer that I'd never recommend putting anything like this in actual shipping code, and that if you do, it's totally not my fault. This can be fun/interesting to do for educational purposes, though.

This isn't going to be an exact science, since the language itself doesn't have any actual concept of a "singleton". Basically, we're just looking for Objective-C classes that have class methods with certain giveaway prefixes. If we find one of those, there's a good chance that we have a singleton.

With that in mind:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static BOOL ClassIsSingleton(Class class) {
    unsigned int methodCount = 0;
    Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(object_getClass(class), &methodCount);

    @try {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < methodCount; i++) {
            Method eachMethod = methods[i];

            // only consider class methods with no arguments
            if (method_getNumberOfArguments(eachMethod) != 2) {
                continue;
            }

            char *returnType = method_copyReturnType(eachMethod);

            @try {
                // only consider class methods that return objects
                if (strcmp(returnType, @encode(id)) != 0) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            @finally {
                free(returnType);
            }

            NSString *name = NSStringFromSelector(method_getName(methods[i]));

            // look for class methods with telltale prefixes
            if ([name hasPrefix:@"shared"]) {
                return YES;
            } else if ([name hasPrefix:@"standard"]) {
                return YES;
            } else if ([name hasPrefix:@"default"]) {
                return YES;
            } else if ([name hasPrefix:@"main"]) {
                return YES;
            } // feel free to add any additional prefixes here that I may have neglected
        }
    }
    @finally {
        free(methods);
    }

    return NO;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *singletons = [NSMutableArray new];

        int classCount = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);

        Class *classes = (Class *)malloc(classCount * sizeof(Class));

        @try {
            classCount = objc_getClassList(classes, classCount);

            for (int i = 0; i < classCount; i++) {
                Class eachClass = classes[i];

                if (ClassIsSingleton(eachClass)) {
                    [singletons addObject:NSStringFromClass(eachClass)];
                }
            }
        }
        @finally {
            free(classes);
        }

        NSLog(@"Singletons: %@", singletons);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very clever!  How about, for each class method that returns an object, call it, check if that object is an instance of the class.  If it is, call the method again and compare the two objects for strong equality.  If they are the same, its even better evidence that you found a singleton.

Comment: That seems like a great idea, until someone introduces a method like:

+ (NSError *)eraseTheHardDrive;

:-P

Comment: You should limit yourself to calling methods that start with init.
In fact,you might get a good stab at it by calling the alloc method twice and comparing those for exact equality.  Don't give the objects a change to formally init themselves.  Of course, some singletons don't use the pattern but then this is an open-ended problem

Comment: @JeffLaing - I don't like that logic, because classes like `NSString` would be falsely identified as singletons. And there also could be classes that offer traditional singleton methods, but for whom `init` might return unique objects.

Comment: I don't like it either - there are lots of cases where the alloc method returns one object, and the init switches in a different one.  That's why the pattern says "self = [[class alloc] init..]".  There is no *right* answer to this question, only heuristics that will help you go close.  (Note: I don't understand how init returning "unique objects" qualifies as a singleton)

Comment: ... but my point was, you don't need to call eraseTheHardDrive if you are looking for singletons.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't really work, though, for the reasons Rob listed. NSFileManager is a good example of this; it has a singleton defaultInstance, but its init produces unique objects. It's better just to look for the naming conventions, IMO, especially since most singletons expect you to use a special class method, not init.

Comment: But that's because NSFileManager is *not really* a singleton - my understanding is that it gives you a unique instance-per-thread and you are never going to be able to statically analyse code and detect that sort of behavior.  What about a class that returns an object based on the current hour, so that you get a single instance for ODD hours and another for EVEN?  Ludicrous but hopefully it illustrates the problem with the definition.  Tagged NSNumber instances (ie, every [NSNumber numberWithInt:5] is the same object) are not singletons.